Asymptotic properties of estimators for general time series model
my question concerns the asymptotic properties of estimators in time series analysis. In particular I am interested in the behavior of the estimators for time series NOT being an ARMA time series. So let $(Y_t)_{t \in I \subset \mathbb{N}}$ be a univariate time series. We may assume that the time series follows some updating equation of the form:
$Y_t = g(Y_{t-1}, ..., Y_{t-p}, f(\epsilon_{t-1}, ..., \epsilon_{t-q}), \epsilon_t)$
where $\epsilon_t$ are $iid$ innovations with $\epsilon_t \sim (0, \sigma^2)$. $f(\epsilon_{t-1}, ..., \epsilon_{t-q})$ is some sort of moving average like part to enable the time series to have a decaying autodependence (instead of cutoff). $g$ is the function that handles the autodependence. Note that for the special choice, where $g$ and $f$ are linear functions, we obtain the classical ARMA model. We may assume that $g$ is parametrized by parameters $\phi$ and $f$ by parameters $\theta$. What I am interested in are conditions that are sufficient for the consistency and asymptotic normality of the MLE estimators for $\phi$ and $\theta$. In several papers (that make a special choice for the functions $g$ and $f$) I came across stationarity and mixing being conditions. However, I am wondering if these conditions would be sufficient for the quite general model I gave here.
Any hints to papers/books/websites etc. would be much appreciated. A direct answer is also good of course :D.

Halbert White ( top theoretical econometrician who died a few years ago )  has written a book ( or books ? ) on model mis-specification. But my guess is that they probably cover the case where things are correctly specified and that's what your question is essentially about.  So I suggest that you check out his material either in his book or his papers. I'll see if I can find a link to the book that I'm referring to.

He's written many books but this is the one I'm referring to. https://www.google.com/books/edition/Estimation_Inference_and_Specification_A/hnNpQSf7ZlAC?hl=en

Thank you for your comment, I will try to look the book up in our library. Does it also include Time Series?

Hi Red: Halbert White was a time-series econometrician so the book will definitely have a time-series flavor. If that book doesn't exactly answer your questions, I bet there will be references in it that will atleast be helpful.
